# jquery progress bar with start and end values

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

Jquery progress bar shows the output from start point to it's value using below code. I need to start value from middle point to given another point.

Ex: I need to highlight 20 - 30 location from the bar of 0-100.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
        value: 37
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what you describe doesn't fit into a definition of progressbar (at least not [UI/API/1.8/Progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Progressbar))

Comment: @MichalKlouda Is there any other method available to highlight given part of the php bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay , Assuming that you are using Jquery UI progress bar and you need to do some thing when the progress bar on your process and you need to change the colour or give some effect when your process is between 20% to 30 %

for that you need to have set interval method some what like this

```
$("#progressbar").data("progress", setInterval(function() {
  if(percentComplete => 20 && percentComplete <= 30) {
    // Do highlighting here
  }
  $("#progressbar").progressbar( { value: percentComplete } );
}, 200));
```

The above code may not be a ready to use solution it is just an attempt to convey the approach to solve your problem

Comment: but no any results.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
   
    <script>
    $("#progressbar").data("progress", setInterval(function() {
       if(percentComplete => 20 && percentComplete <= 30) {
         // Do what ever you want here 
       }
       $("#progressbar").progressbar( { value: percentComplete } );
     }, 200));
   </script>

Comment: I think its better you put your html code and also how your are binding it to your process so that we can analyze well @eduLanka It is really a question which has research effort

Comment: Please explain which jquery version support for that

Comment: I prefer using latest version especially when using jquery UI , version number recommended is [Jquery 1.7.1 ] (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js) and [jquery UI 1.9] (http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.zip)